# Discover whether user is a member of an AD group via jquery

Tags: 2010, jquery, active-directory, spservices

Using jquery and/or spservices, how can I know whether the current user is a member of an AD group?

[I have found this](http://sympmarc.com/2010/01/29/determining-if-a-user-is-in-a-permission-group-with-sharepoints-web-services/), but I think it only checks for membership in a Sharepoint group.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this comes up often. jQuery/SPServices/SP REST do not have any means of diving into local AD to find membership.

Comment: I think you are right about this.  I was just hoping that the info just on the current user would be somewhere gettable.

Comment: Maybe I can add some aspx code in the master page that does determines if the user is a member of a certain group and sets a flag that is accessible by javascript?  I am building a helpdesk, and I want to present different options if members of a certain group use it.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to build your own server side API that you reference somehow.

Comment: I figured out a way and posted an answer in the duplicate: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144488/check-an-user-belongs-to-a-ad-group-inside-sharepoint-group-using-spservices-jqu